# Form not working unless underyling query re-saved

Tags: ms-access

I'm a newcomer to Access trying to cobble things together from helpful information I've found here.

I have a form that needs to populate the fields based on a combo box selection in the form header. The form is based on an underlying query with the following criteria for field "StudID" [Forms]![frmStudConsentUpdate]![cmbStud] where cmbStud is my combo box. The combo box pulls in StudID, StudFN, StudLN with StudID as the bound columnn. The after update event requeries the form (Me.Requery). This works beautifully, but only if I first open the form in design view, open the Record Source, and save it. I don't make any changes at all, but once I've done this the form works. Otherwise, nothing happens when I select a student in the combo box. Any thoughts on what I need to do to make this work without having to re-save the underlying query?

Comment: It seems OK on the surface, is it possible to upload your database? If so I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is old bug in MS Access, I have no idea why they still didn't fix it:
If underlying form's query has in criteria form's control and the form was filtered once (at start or manually/using VBA), it doesn't accept new values from form's control and uses old value.

Workaround: create public function, which returns control's value and use it in criteria instead of `[Forms]![frmStudConsentUpdate]![cmbStud]`. You will need to create function for each control or use this function:

```
Public Function GetControlValue(strFormName As String, strControlName As String, Optional strSubFormControlName As Variant, Optional varDefault As Variant) As Variant
' Returns : Variant, value of control in form/subform
' Comments:
' Params  :
'           strFormName
'           strControlName
'           strSubFormControlName
'           varDefault - value returned if control is not accessible
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

If IsMissing(strSubFormControlName) Or Nz(strSubFormControlName, "") = "" Then
    GetControlValue = Forms(strFormName).Controls(strControlName).Value
Else
    GetControlValue = Forms(strFormName).Controls(strSubFormControlName).Form.Controls(strControlName).Value
End If

ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    If Not IsMissing(varDefault) Then
        GetControlValue = varDefault
    End If
    Resume ExitHere
End Function
```

In criteria use function call `GetControlValue("frmStudConsentUpdate","cmbStud")` instead of  `[Forms]![frmStudConsentUpdate]![cmbStud]`

Comment: Thanks so much, Sergey. I was able to implement your solution and create the public function, and I changed the criteria for the query. However, the form still fails to update after the value is selected in the combo box unless I open the underlying query and save it first. Am I perhaps missing a step?

Comment: Try to save the query in recordsource as saved query and select it as recordsource

Comment: I thought of the same thing, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I think I figured out a different solution without using the filter that's interfering. Thank you so much for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

In your afterupdate for your cmbStud combobox, create code that refreshes the recordsource to

`me.recordsource = "SELECT * FROM {yourQueryName} WHERE StudID = '" & me!cmbStud & "'"`